# graph.facebook.com - Transport security block

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, plist

Error: Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

When trying to access graph.facebook.com/ etc
I already put 
NSAllowsArbitraryLoads
           on plist, but it keeps on giving this error.

Any solution, please?

EDIT: I have this and it isn't working. Same error

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>  <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Please show the relevant section of your plist in context and confirm that you have modified the correct plist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your info.plist to include a few more entries for facebook.com.

From the [Facebook iOS 9 Migration doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>                
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```