# Facebook iOS SDK: ATS exception

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Question about iOS 10 ATS. From 2017 Apple will not accept any exceptions anymore to ATS unless there is a very good reason. Based on a post on StackOverflow ([graph.facebook.com - Transport security block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554104/graph-facebook-com-transport-security-block)) I added some exceptions for Facebook. Is this still necessary or is it save to remove these exceptions from now on?

Answer (score 0):

Per Facebook's iOS SDK release notes, it does not require whitelisting as of v4.10.0 (February 10th, 2016).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4x

The Facebook Audience Network SDK is also 100% compatible, due to its use of SFSafariViewController:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ios/ats

Hope this helps!